# Problema al gestionar XML en Java con SAX

Tags: java, xml, sax

mi problema es que tengo que leer solo los apellidos de un fichero de empleados XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Empleados>
    <empleado>
        <id>1</id><apellido>FERNANDEZ</apellido><dep>10</dep><salario>1000.45</salario>
    </empleado>
    <empleado>
        <id>2</id><apellido>GIL</apellido><dep>20</dep><salario>2400.6</salario>
    </empleado>
    <empleado>
        <id>3</id><apellido>LOPEZ</apellido><dep>10</dep><salario>3000.0</salario>
    </empleado>
    <empleado>
        <id>4</id><apellido>RAMOS</apellido><dep>10</dep><salario>1500.56</salario>
    </empleado>
    <empleado>
        <id>5</id><apellido>SEVILLA</apellido><dep>30</dep><salario>2200.0</salario>
    </empleado>
    <empleado>
        <id>6</id><apellido>CASILLA</apellido><dep>30</dep><salario>1435.87</salario>
    </empleado>
    <empleado>
        <id>7</id><apellido>REY</apellido><dep>20</dep><salario>2000.0</salario>
    </empleado>
</Empleados>
```

Necesito solo coger los apellidos de cada empleado, pero solo consigo filtar los comienzos y finales de cada elemento del archivo. Hasta aquí mi ejercicio.

```
    public class Actividad0601 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, SAXException {

        XMLReader lectorXML = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        GestionContenidoID gestor = new GestionContenidoID();
        lectorXML.setContentHandler(gestor);
        InputSource fileXML = new InputSource("Empleados.xml");
        lectorXML.parse(fileXML);
    }
}

class GestionContenidoID extends DefaultHandler {
    public GestionContenidoID() {
        super();
    }

    public void startDocument() {
        System.out.println("Comienzo del Documento XML");
    }

    public void endDocument() {
        System.out.println("Final del Documento XML");
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String nombre, String nombreC, Attributes atts) {
        if (nombre.equalsIgnoreCase("apellido")) {
            System.out.printf("\t Principio Elemento: %s %n", nombre);
        }
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String nombre, String nombreC) {
        if (nombre.equalsIgnoreCase("apellido")) {
            System.out.printf("\t Final Elemento: %s %n", nombre);
        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int inicio, int longitud) throws SAXException {
        String car = new String(ch, inicio, longitud);
        // quitar saltos de l�nea
        car = car.replaceAll("[\t\n]", "");
        System.out.printf("\t\t Caracteres: %s %n", car);
    }

}// fin GestionContenido
```

No se realmente como tratar cada elemento del XML, porque no se como accede cada elemento a los caracteres que contienen y no puedo filtrar los datos solo desde los métodos `startElement` y `endElement`

Con este código la salida del programa es la siguiente:

```
Comienzo del Documento XML
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres: 1 
 Principio Elemento: apellido 
     Caracteres: FERNANDEZ 
 Final Elemento: apellido 
     Caracteres: 10 
     Caracteres: 1000.45 
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres: 2 
 Principio Elemento: apellido 
     Caracteres: GIL 
 Final Elemento: apellido 
     Caracteres: 20 
     Caracteres: 2400.6 
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres: 3 
 Principio Elemento: apellido 
     Caracteres: LOPEZ 
 Final Elemento: apellido 
     Caracteres: 10 
     Caracteres: 3000.0 
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres: 4 
 Principio Elemento: apellido 
     Caracteres: RAMOS 
 Final Elemento: apellido 
     Caracteres: 10 
     Caracteres: 1500.56 
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres: 5 
 Principio Elemento: apellido 
     Caracteres: SEVILLA 
 Final Elemento: apellido 
     Caracteres: 30 
     Caracteres: 2200.0 
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres: 6 
 Principio Elemento: apellido 
     Caracteres: CASILLA 
 Final Elemento: apellido 
     Caracteres: 30 
     Caracteres: 1435.87 
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres: 7 
 Principio Elemento: apellido 
     Caracteres: REY 
 Final Elemento: apellido 
     Caracteres: 20 
     Caracteres: 2000.0 
     Caracteres:  
     Caracteres:  
Final del Documento XML
```

Tal vez no esté entendiendo bien como funciona SAX. Muchas gracias de antemano por las respuestas.

Comment: Parece correcto. Quizás podrías intentar implementar también el método `warning` para ver si el parseador está lanzando alguna excepción que dé más información.

Comment: O incluse imprimir en StartElement el nodmbre de cada nodo...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

📖 SAX es un *parser* basado en eventos (*event-driven*).<sup>1</sup> Por ejemplo, cada vez que encuentra algún elemento en el XML, se invoca el `startElement` de la instancia de `org.xml.sax.ContentHandler`, y así con los otros eventos.

No obstante, SAX no mantiene o no construye una representación permanente de la estructura del documento. De ahí que se deba guardar el sitio en el que uno está parado, es decir, guardar en algún lado el estado actual de ejecución para efectuar una acción o un conjunto de acciones.

💻 Para la tarea que tienes entre manos, bastaría, en principio, con una variable *booleana*. Digamos, por ejemplo, que se llame `isApellido`. Esto es:

```
private boolean isApellido;

public void startElement(String uri, String nombre, String nombreC, Attributes atts) {
    if (nombre.equalsIgnoreCase("apellido")) {
        isApellido = true;
    }
}

public void endElement(String uri, String nombre, String nombreC) {
    if (nombre.equalsIgnoreCase("apellido")) {
        isApellido = false;
    }
}

public void characters(char[] ch, int inicio, int longitud) throws SAXException {
    if (isApellido) {
        String car = new String(ch, inicio, longitud);
        // quitar saltos de línea
        car = car.replaceAll("[\t\n]", "");
        System.out.println("Apellido: " + car);
    }
}
```

En procesamiento más "complejos", normalmente se utilizan listas o pilas o mapas, o una combinación de los anteriores.<sup>2</sup>

---

📓 *Notas*

1. Flanagan, David. *Java in a nutshell.* Beijing Sebastopol, CA: O'Reilly, 2005. p. 276.
2. Véase un *ejemplo* en [*SAX Parser and DefaultHandler Example*](http://howtodoinjava.com/xml/how-to-parse-an-xml-using-sax-parser-and-defaulthandler/).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, finalmente lo hice usando booleanos para diferenciar donde estaba, un saludo